# Unable to start Electron program

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Trying to boot Electron program with `npm start` and I get:

```
ReferenceError: relectron is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (P:\work\electron\tasky\main.js:5:30)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
at loadApplicationPackage (P:\Work\Electron\Tasky\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:109:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (P:\Work\Electron\Tasky\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\main.js:155:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:786:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:798:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:645:32)
```

I have Node.js installed, and I've already run `npm install -g electron` and `npm install electron --save`

As a newer Electron user, I have no idea what this means or what to do about it.

Comment: It says relectron is not defined. Seems it is a typo.

Comment: how is this java related?

Comment: @TasosK. I'm an idiot, thank you

Comment: @Stultuske I didn't really think when I was adding that tag, and I accidentally rejected your fix, I fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: My fix? I didn't edit your post/tags. I just added the comment.

Comment: @Stultuske Oh, well someone else did try to remove it and I accidentally rejected it, no harm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo in my main.js script

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;
```

was acidentally

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = relectron;
```